# Add object to the beginning of an observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular component that lazy loads data to an `Observable<Item[]>` through a `BehaviorSubject<Item[]>` when the scroll position of a container reaches the bottom.

The needed properties and the `init()` function that initializes the list of items look like

```
private _itemList: BehaviorSubject<Item[]>;
private _done = new BehaviorSubject(false);
private _loading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
private _page: number;
itemList: Observable<Item[]>;

init() {
    this._page = 0;
    this._itemList = new BehaviorSubject([])
    this.mapAndUpdate();
    this.itemList = this._itemList.asObservable()
    .scan((acc, val) => {
        return acc.concat(val);
    });
}
```

and the function that does the actual fetching of data

```
mapAndUpdate() {
    if (this._done.value || this._loading.value) {
        return;
    }

    this._loading.next(true);
    const offset = this._page * 20;
    const limit = 20;
    return this.service.getItems(limit, offset)
    .do(res => {
        this._itemList.next(res.items);
        this._loading.next(false);
        if (!res.items.length) {
            this._done.next(true);
        }
    }).subscribe();
}
```

In the same component, I'm subscribing to realtime push events that can emit new items which should be added to the beginning of the array instead of the end of the array.

```
subscribeToItemsChannel() {
    this.pusherService.getItemsChannel().bind('new-item', (res: any) => {
        const item = res.item as Item;

        // Emitting the item with next() will only add it to the end of the array
        this._itemList.next([item]);
    });
}
```

I've tried to use a boolean value `shouldPrepend` that I set in the realtime function handler together with

```
.scan((acc, val) => {
    if(this._shouldPrepend) {
        return val.concat(acc);
    } else {
        return acc.concat(val);         
    }
});
```

which does add the new item to the beginning, but also messes up the order of the rest of the array and it doesn't feel like the correct rxjs way to do it either.

How can I at any given random moment prepend an object to an `Observable<array>`?

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/madenocone/1/edit?js,console) that better explains the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand using a special `this._shouldPrepend` variable seems weird because it breaks the "pure functions" paradigm.

So personally I'd emit objects that contain information whether I what to append them or prepend.

```
enum Action { Append, Prepend };

...

numberList = bSubject
  .scan((acc, val) => val.action === Action.Prepend
    ? [val.value, ...acc]
    : [...acc, val.value]
  );

...

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Fetching data... Numberlist is now: ');
  bSubject.next({ action: Action.Append, value: i});
  i++;
}, 3000);
```

Your updated demo: http://jsbin.com/wasihog/edit?js,console

Eventually if you don't want to change the way you emit values you can have two merged Subjects. One that prepends values and another one that appends values.

```
const append$ = new Subject();
const prepend$ = new Subject();

Observable.merge(
  append$.map(value => ({ action: Action.Append, value })),
  prepend$.map(value => ({ action: Action.Prepend, value })),
)
```

You can see that you'll emit like `append$.next(1)` and the value will be wrapped with an object that tells `scan` what to do with it.

Comment: Great suggestions, I'm gonna try to adapt it to my actual need and see if it works! :) Thanks!

Comment: @martin
Being more used to Redux in normal cases, I went with the first suggestion of including an action. Great input, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this one, but it looks like you want **startWith**.

```
//emit (1,2,3)
const source = of(1, 2, 3);

//start with 0
const example = source.pipe(startWith(0));

//output: 0,1,2,3
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This code sample is from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html